# Flask Error handling not working properly

Tags: python, flask, exception, flask-restful

I have a custom exception shown below where functions are raising these exceptions.

```
class UnauthorizedToSendException(HTTPException):
    code = 400
    description = 'Unauthorized to Send.'
```

They are then defined in `Flask`'s `create_app()` as follows:

```
def handle_custom_exceptions(e):
    response = {"error": e.description, "message": ""}
    if len(e.args) > 0:
        response["message"] = e.args[0]
    # Add some logging so that we can monitor different types of errors
    app.logger.error(f"{e.description}: {response['message']}")
    return jsonify(response), e.code

 app.register_error_handler(UnauthorizedToSendException, handle_custom_exceptions)
```

When this exception is raised below:

```
class LaptopStatus(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        raise UnauthorizedToSendException('you are unauthorized to send')
```

However, the output is always this way:

```
{
    "message": "you are unauthorized to send"
}
```

Is there something missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask_restful.Api` has its own error handling implementation that mostly replaces Flask's `errorhandler` functionality, so using the `Flask.errorhandler` decorator or `Flask.register_error_handler` won't work.

There are a couple solutions to this.

### Don't Inherit from `HTTPException` and set `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS`

The flask-restful error routing has short circuits for handling exceptions that don't inherit from `HTTPException`, and if you set your Flask app to propagate exceptions, it will send the exception to be handled by normal Flask's handlers.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


app = Flask(__name__)

# Note that this doesn't inherit from HTTPException
class UnauthorizedToSendException(Exception):
    code = 400
    description = 'Unauthorized to Send'


@app.errorhandler(UnauthorizedToSendException)
def handle_unauth(e: Exception):
    rsp = {"error": e.description, "message": ""}
    if len(e.args) > 0:
        rsp["message"] = e.args[0]

    app.logger.error(f"{e.description}: {rsp['message']}")
    return flask.jsonify(rsp), e.code


class LaptopStatus(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        raise UnauthorizedToSendException("Not authorized")


api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(LaptopStatus, '/status')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting this is important otherwise your raised
    # exception will just generate a regular exception
    app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
    app.run()
```

Running this I get...

```
#> python flask-test-propagate.py
# ... blah blah ...


#> curl http://localhost:5000/status
{"error":"Unauthorized to Send","message":"Not authorized"}
```

### Replace `flask_restul.Api.error_router`

This will override the behavior of the `Api` class's `error_router` method, and just use the original handler that Flask would use.

You can see it's just a monkey-patch of the class's method with...

```
Api.error_router = lambda self, hnd, e: hnd(e)
```

This will allow you to subclass `HTTPException` and override flask-restful's behavior.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

# patch the Api class with a custom error router
# that just use's flask's handler (which is passed in as hnd)
Api.error_router = lambda self, hnd, e: hnd(e)

app = Flask(__name__)


class UnauthorizedToSendException(HTTPException):
    code = 400
    description = 'Unauthorized to Send'


@app.errorhandler(UnauthorizedToSendException)
def handle_unauth(e: Exception):
    print("custom!")
    rsp = {"error": e.description, "message": ""}
    if len(e.args) > 0:
        rsp["message"] = e.args[0]

    app.logger.error(f"{e.description}: {rsp['message']}")
    return flask.jsonify(rsp), e.code


class LaptopStatus(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        raise UnauthorizedToSendException("Not authorized")


api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(LaptopStatus, '/status')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

### Switch to using `flask.views.MethodView`

Documentation:

- [`flask.views.MethodView`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.views.MethodView)

Just thought of this, and it's a more drastic change to your code, but flask has facilities for making building REST APIs easier. `flask-restful` isn't exactly abandoned, but the pace of changes have slowed down the last several years, and various components like the error handling system have become too inflexible.

If you're using `flask-restful` specifically for the `Resource` implementation, you can switch to the `MethodView`, and then you don't need to do any kind of workarounds.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException


app = Flask(__name__)


class UnauthorizedToSendException(HTTPException):
    code = 400
    description = 'Unauthorized to Send'


@app.errorhandler(UnauthorizedToSendException)
def handle_unauth(e: Exception):
    rsp = {"error": e.description, "message": ""}
    if len(e.args) > 0:
        rsp["message"] = e.args[0]

    app.logger.error(f"{e.description}: {rsp['message']}")
    return flask.jsonify(rsp), e.code


class LaptopStatusApi(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        raise UnauthorizedToSendException("Not authorized")


app.add_url_rule("/status", view_func=LaptopStatusApi.as_view("laptopstatus"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score -2):

read the https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/errorhandling/

but: See werkzeug.exception for default HTTPException classes.
For HTTP400 (werkzeug.exception.BadRequest)